# Animation flickers with Firefox 18.0.1 (due to RequestAnimationFrame?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, parallax

i used this http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-interactive-street-view-jquery tutorial to create an intro for one of our customers:

http://f-bilandia.de/kunstmann/bronski/

It used to work really good on all browsers. When I updated to the newest stable version of Firefox (FF 18.0.1) however, there is heavy flickering while changing the images.

When reading the release notes of the newest version, i saw that ff has a new Javascript engine and has improved image quality with a new HTML scaling algorithm. Maybe it's because of that? Other possible solutions?

Below you can see the code i've used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $doc = $(document);
        var $win = $(window);

        // dimensions - we want to cache them on window resize
        var windowHeight, windowWidth;
        var fullHeight, scrollHeight;
        var streetImgWidth = 1024, streetImgHeight = 640;
        calculateDimensions();

        var currentPosition = -1, targetPosition = 0;
        var $videoContainer = $('.street-view');
        var video = $('.street-view > img')[0];
        var $hotspotElements = $('[data-position]');


        // handling resize and scroll events

        function calculateDimensions() {
            windowWidth = $win.width();
            windowHeight = $win.height();
            fullHeight = $('#main').height();
            scrollHeight = fullHeight - windowHeight;
        }

        function handleResize() {
            calculateDimensions();
            resizeBackgroundImage();
            handleScroll();
        }

        function handleScroll() {
            targetPosition = $win.scrollTop() / scrollHeight;
        }

        // main render loop
        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
          return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
                  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
                  window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
                  window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
                  function(/* function */ callback, /* DOMElement */ element){
                    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                  };
        })();


        function animloop(){
            if ( Math.floor(currentPosition*5000) != Math.floor(targetPosition*5000) ) {
                currentPosition += (targetPosition - currentPosition) / 5;
                render(currentPosition);
            }
          requestAnimFrame(animloop);
        }






        // rendering


        function render( position ) {
            // position the elements
            var minY = -windowHeight, maxY = windowHeight;
            $.each($hotspotElements,function(index,element){
                var $hotspot = $(element);
                var elemPosition = Number( $hotspot.attr('data-position') );
                var elemSpeed = Number( $hotspot.attr('data-speed') );
                var elemY = windowHeight/2 + elemSpeed * (elemPosition-position) * scrollHeight;
                if ( elemY < minY || elemY > maxY ) {
                    $hotspot.css({'visiblity':'none', top: '-1000px','webkitTransform':'none'});
                } else {
                    $hotspot.css({'visiblity':'visible', top: elemY, position: 'fixed'});
                }
            });


            renderVideo( position );
        }



        function resizeBackgroundImage(){
            // get image container size
            var scale = Math.max( windowHeight/streetImgHeight , windowWidth/streetImgWidth );
            var width = scale * streetImgWidth , height = scale * streetImgHeight;
            var left = (windowWidth-width)/2, top = (windowHeight-height)/2;
            $videoContainer
                      .width(width).height(height)
                      .css('position','fixed')
                      .css('left',left+'px')
                      .css('top',top+'px');
        }





        // video handling

        var imageSeqLoader = new ProgressiveImageSequence( "street/vid-{index}.jpg" , 387 , {
            indexSize: 4,
            initialStep: 16,
            onProgress: handleLoadProgress,
            onComplete: handleLoadComplete,
            stopAt: 1
        } );
                    // there seems to be a problem with ie 
                    // calling the callback several times
        var loadCounterForIE = 0; 
        imageSeqLoader.loadPosition(currentPosition,function(){
            loadCounterForIE++;
            if ( loadCounterForIE == 1 ) {
                renderVideo(currentPosition);
                imageSeqLoader.load();
                imageSeqLoader.load();
                imageSeqLoader.load();
                imageSeqLoader.load();
            }
        });


        var currentSrc, currentIndex;

        function renderVideo(position) {
            var index = Math.round( currentPosition * (imageSeqLoader.length-1) );
            var img = imageSeqLoader.getNearest( index );
            var nearestIndex = imageSeqLoader.nearestIndex;
            if ( nearestIndex < 0 ) nearestIndex = 0;
            var $img = $(img);
            var src;
            if ( !!img ) {
                src = img.src;
                if ( src != currentSrc ) {
                    video.src = src;
                    currentSrc = src;
                }
            }
        }



        $('body').append('<div id="loading-bar" style="">Loading...</div>');

        function handleLoadProgress() {
            var progress = imageSeqLoader.getLoadProgress() * 100;
            $('#loading-bar').css({width:progress+'%',opacity:1});
        }

        function handleLoadComplete() {
            $('#loading-bar').css({width:'100%',opacity:0,display: "none"});
            $("html, body").css("overflow", "auto");
            $("html, body").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
            $("nav").css("display", "block");
            $("#preloader").fadeOut("slow");
            $("#scroll-hint").css("display", "block");
        }




        $win.resize( handleResize );
        $win.scroll( handleScroll );

        handleResize();
        animloop();




    });
```

Comment: The tutorial's demo works fine for me without any flicker http://360langstrasse.sf.tv/tutorial/4/ on FF 18.0.1, so perhaps you have a greasemonkey script or plugin or extension that is behaving badly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I don't think this is the reason, because it used to work and still works with any other browser, FF 17 & prior

Answer (score 1):

Inside your "render( position )" function the following lines seem like they should be refactored.

```
            if ( elemY < minY || elemY > maxY ) {
                $hotspot.css({'visiblity':'none', top: '-1000px','webkitTransform':'none'});
            } else {
                $hotspot.css({'visiblity':'visible', top: elemY, position: 'fixed'});
            }
```

- For one visibility is spelled wrong and there is no "none" value for it (it would be "hidden"). Just use "display" with "none" and "" values.
- The "top", "webkitTransform", and "position" keys seem unnecessary. If the element is not visible there's no need to set the top, and why wouldn't the element always be fixed position?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Visibility was indeed spelled wrong. Just changed that. But "top" "webkit-transform" and position do make sense, because they are responsible for the parallax moving of the hotspots. Unfortunately it didn't fix the flickering in FF 18.

Comment: @Bene84 - I wasn't specific enough about the TOP, I meant when you set top to -1000 even though the element is no longer visible, it is unnecessary.